# Why does std::ratio not support comparison operators?

Tags: c++, c++11

As the C++ Standard Library normally provides overloaded operators for its classes, I was wondering why there are comparison functions(actually not really functions but structs with overloaded ()-operator) but no comparison operators for the std::ratio class(es).

Im my opinion they would provide a lot better use- and readabilty and could be performed on compile-time as well.

Even if their particular solution would need template-metaprogramming using structs, wrapping it into another function like that should be no problem:

```
template<intmax_t N1, intmax_t D1, intmax_t N2, intmax_t D2>
constexpr bool operator==(const ratio<N1, D1>& first, const ratio<N2, D2>& second) {
    return ratio_equal<ratio<N1,D1>, ratio<N2,D2>>();
}
```

Actually works for me and could be adopted easily for all the other operators as well

So am I missing something or has anyone an idea why they decided not to support operators here?

Comment: How often do you use ratios as objects and not as template parameters?

Comment: Well actually this is a really good point, but still not a reason why one would not implement the above feature.

Comment: Retaining the exactness of the ratio for the comparison requires cross-multiplication of the numerators and denominators, which could silently overflow the int type being used.

Comment: Yeah, but that could also happen with the provided functions(actually they are structs with an overloaded ()-operator i know), couldn't it? And also wrapping whatever solution is provided should not change the behaviour anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ratio` class is not designed to be instantiated; it has no data members, so any objects based on it don't contain any information beyond the class type itself. Since operators must be called against objects, not types, it would be pointless to provide them. It would even be counter-productive, since it would imply that instantiating the class would be useful.

If you truly need run-time objects instead of compile-time types, I suggest that `ratio` is probably not the appropriate choice.

Comment: I have to agree, that this is probably on of the most important reasons (as also Barry said). But they do indeed have members (they are static but...), see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/ratio/ratio

Comment: @mr.green static members don't belong to an object, they belong to the class itself. An object of that class type will be empty, although the standard requires it to take up at least one byte.

Comment: That's what I wrote (or meant with "they are static...") but I think we were just talking past each other

Comment: @mr.green do you disagree with my reasoning then? The operators can only work with objects, and the class is not intended to create objects. Thus no operators.

Comment: Yes I do, this was the main thing I  missed when thinking about it yesterday or even the day before yesterday depends on ones timezone.

Answer (score 3):

Most likely back when the proposal [N2661](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2661.htm) was written, constexpr didn't exist yet. The first occurance of constexpr I found was in [N2235](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2235.pdf), so chances are at least no compiler had it implemented and it was probably not even sure it will be considered in the future standard.
That just a guess though, maybe not even worth this answer.